# If Graph G is a set, then Domain (G) and Range (G) are also sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm teaching myself set theory from Charles Pinter's book and trying to show that if graph $G$ is a set, then it's Domain$(G)$= $\{x \, |\, (x,y)\in G\}$ and Range ($G$) = $\{y\, |\, (x, y) \in G\}$ are both sets. My intuition tells me that if Graph $G$ is a set, than any subset of it will also be a set... But how to show Domain and Range are subsets of $G$?

Comment: They are not subsets of $G$. Try to find different sets that they are subsets of.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Pinter's book, but this is a classic instance where the Axiom of Replacement (aka Substitution) is needed, in a axiomatic treatment (specifically, using the ZF axioms).

Comment: What is your definition of $(x,y)$?

Comment: @MichaelWeiss  Although there's an easy proof using the axiom of replacement, there's also a proof using just the axiom of union. (See the answer by Green Park.)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to math.stackechange.com!

Remember that $(x, y)=\{\{x\}, \{x, y\}\}$. Thus, if $(x, y)\in G$, we have $x, y\in \{x, y\}\in (x, y)\in G$.

Therefore, we have $\{x, y\}\in \bigcup G$, so $x, y\in \bigcup \bigcup G$.

Can you finish the proof from this?

I am not familiar with that book, but this will probably help you. Please comment in case you need clarification.

Comment: Why someone downvoted this answer?

Comment: Not sure why you need a double union. Since graph G is a set, and union of sets is a set ...

Comment: You need a set contains all the elements of the domain and the range of $G$, and then use the axiom of comprehension to restrict it to the elements you want. $\bigcup G$ does not contain the elements of the domain and of the range of $G$. It contains pairs $\{x, y\}$, where $x, y$ are the things you want. You need to take the union again to open up those pairs.